# Batch file to delete specific line numbers

Tags: batch-file, line, lines

I have a file that updates every 24 hours, with the new data added to the end (as it should), but some of the data at the start of the file becomes irrelevant. What I need is for a batch file that would delete lines #3 and #4, and then save the file using the same name.

So, for example, let's say the file is file.txt and it looks like this:

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D
5. E
6. F

I need the 3rd and 4th lines removed, so the file will now look like this:

1. A
2. B
3. E
4. F

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something? Post some code.

Comment: I haven't, because I have no knowledge of writing batch files. I know this is kind of asking to be spoon fed, but I wouldn't know where to start, and none of my Google searches have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the batch code to modify a file by removing line 3 and 4.

It is fully commented. So I hope you understand it.

You need to modify path and name of file to modify in fifth line.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define name of file to modify and check existence.
set "FileToModify=C:\Temp\Test.tmp"
if not exist "%FileToModify%" goto EndBatch

rem Define name of temporary file and delete this file if it currently
rem exists for example because of a breaked previous batch execution.
set "TempFile=%TEMP%\FileUpdate.tmp"
if exist "%TempFile%" del "%TempFile%"

rem Define a line number environment variable for temporary usage.
set "Line=0"

rem Process the file to modify line by line whereby empty lines are
rem skipped by command FOR and all other lines are just copied to
rem the temporary file with the exception of line 3 and line 4.
for /F "useback delims=" %%L in ("%FileToModify%") do (
    if !Line! GTR 3 (
        echo %%L>>"%TempFile%"
    ) else (
        rem Increment line number up to number 4.
        set /A Line+=1
        rem Copy line 1 and 2, but not line 3 and 4.
        if !Line! LSS 3 echo %%L>>"%TempFile%"
    )
)

rem Copy the temporary file being a copy of file to modify with
rem the exception of removed line 3 and 4 over the file to modify.
rem Finally delete the temporary file.
copy /Y "%TempFile%" "%FileToModify%" >nul
del "%TempFile%"

:EndBatch
endlocal
```